# Misplaced No align

Tags: tables

I use the next code to create a table but i get a misplaced no align error in the line i use row color .... can you help me identifying the cause of the problem? thanks a lot !! Athanasios

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Table title.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|}\hline
{\rowcolor[cmyk]{0.2 0 0 0}}$\xi$&$\zeta$&$\Delta$& Surface \rule[-6pt]{0ex}{4ex}\\\hline
$4$ & $3$ & $\neq 0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $3$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$1$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing one pair of curly braces in the line marked `here` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Table title.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|}\hline
\rowcolor[cmyk]{0.2 0 0 0}$\xi$&$\zeta$&$\Delta$& Surface \rule[-6pt]{0ex}{4ex}\\\hline % here -- PS
$4$ & $3$ & $\neq 0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $3$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $<0$ & Surface 1 \\
$4$ & $2$ & $>0$ & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $3$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $2$ & & Surface 1 \\
$3$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$2$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
$1$ & $1$ & & Surface 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the problem solved :-) thanks a lot for your answer